# Can I use Spreedly to assign a subscription to a venue as well as a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreedly

In my app a user has an account, and many venues can belong to each account. The venues are on either a free or premium subscription.

I would like to use Spreedly to sort out recurring billing for each venue. So a user can own multiple venues where some are free and some are premium. Can I do this with Spreedly? All the documentation I have seen assigns a subscription to a user only.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreedly doesn't know or care about the difference between a User or a Venue. These are just names of models that you have determined. So yes, you can do that. If you are following a guide, just apply it to your venue model instead of your user model.